# Array stream not summing

Tags: java

I'm trying to sum an array of Integers. I red @ZouZou 's solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550662/how-do-you-find-the-sum-of-all-the-numbers-in-an-array-in-java) and can't get it to work

```
int [] arr = {1,2,3,4};
int sum = Arrays.stream(arr).sum(); //prints 10
```

I've got

```
public static void proc(Integer[] v) {
    int sum = Arrays.stream(v).sum();
```

and the compiler gives "cannot find symbol method sum".

What is the problem? Is doing it this way any faster than summing with a loop?

Comment: In the link you gave, it used `IntStream`, not `Arrays`.

Answer (score 5):

`Arrays.stream` has few overloaded versions.

`Arrays.stream(int[] arr)` returns `IntStream` which has `sum` method

while

`Arrays.stream(T[] arr)` returns `Stream<T>` (where `T` is generic) which has no `sum` method.

Since you are using `Integer[]` as argument `Arrays.stream(T[] arr)` is invoked which is why compiler informs you about lack of `sum` method.

What you can do here is either changing used type to `int[]` or using something like

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(v).reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0);
```

Since `reduce` returns `Optional<Integer>` I could use `get()` to read its value but this way I would risk

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
```

in case of no elements to stream on (when array is empty like `new Integer[0]`). In this case it is better to use `orElse(0)` which means: *return stored value or `0` if there is no value*.

Comment: what is a reduction operation?

Comment: That is broad topic. I suggest reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html. In short reduction lets you return some new result based on elements  in stream.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.stream(v)` returns a `Stream<Integer>` because `v` is an array of `Integer`'s. There is no `sum()` for `Stream<T>` - take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

If `v` was `int[]`, then `Arrays.stream(v)` would return an [`IntStream` which contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) the `sum()` method you're looking for.

Hope this clarifies what's going on.