# return the sum of values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am given an array of name '`array[]`' with an unknown amount of elements. I am asked to return the sum of all of the values in the array, and I tried to write a `for` loop covering all of the values in the array and adding them together. I think that I am overthinking this, and I should be able to do this in one command but I can't remember.

Here is what I am given:

```
int arraySum(int[] array)
```

I tried:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){ 
    int sum = array[i]; 
} 
return sum;
```

Comment: You mentioned that you have written some code. Care to share that?

Comment: Also then explain what is wrong with it and why it's not working the way you want it to work.

Comment: Using a loop is not overthinking it - it's what you should do. Show us your code and we'll help you see what's wrong.

Comment: i tried: for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){ int sum = array[i]; } return sum;

Comment: am i supposed to put the return statement inside of the loop?

Comment: Better duplicate: [Sum of elements in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31196967/16779120)

Answer (score 4):

Use Java 8 Stream api which gives sum in one line .

```
Arrays.stream(array).sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the problem here:

```
int sum = array[i];
```

because you are creating a new variable `sum` each time the loop make an iteration. You should create your `sum` variable before using it on the loop:

```
int arraySum( int[] array) {
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){ 
       sum = sum + array[i]; 
   } 

   return sum;
}
```

Look that you have to initialize it to zero.

Also, **remember that the arrays starts at the position `0`**. Because of that, you should use

```
i < array.length
```

instead of

```
i <= array.length
```

in your loop condition.

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: Also, sum += array[i]; `=` sum = sum + array[i];

Comment: @Kyle Yes, of course. I just used one of the possible options.

Comment: The `return` statement might work better if it is actually *inside* the method body.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, you are right. Thanks for the point!

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
int arraySum( int[] array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : array) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare (and initialize `sum`). Usually, a sum starts at `0`. Then, you might use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) - you can read it like for-each `value` in the array, do something with the `value` - like add it to `sum`. Finally, return the `sum`. Like,

```
int arraySum(int[] array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int value : array) {
        sum += value;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Or, using an `index` variable like

```
int arraySum(int[] array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        sum += array[index];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Or, you could use the new Java 8+ [stream api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) with [`Arrays.stream(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) and [`IntStream.sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) like

```
int arraySum(int[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).sum();
}
```

And, as pointed out by [@PaulBoddington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3973077/paul-boddington), you could also use [`IntStream.of(int...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of-int...-) and [`IntStream.sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) like

```
int arraySum(int[] array) {
    return IntStream.of(array).sum();
}
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1). If it's completeness you're going for you could add `IntStream.of(array).sum();`

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `sum` is within the for loop. You should declare it outside for loop to use it.

Also, the addition of sum isn't correct as well as the for loop condition.

The updated code should be something similar to following

```
int sum = 0;    
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ 
        sum+ = array[i]; 
 } 
 return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable `sum` outside the loop, else it will re initiate every time. Also, use `+=` operator to add itself.

```
int sum = 0; 
for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){ 
   sum += array[i]; 
 } 
return sum;
```