# How to sum arrays without nested loops?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

```
public class Labwork
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int [][] x = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {11, 12} };
      int [][] y = { {20, 12}, {10, 11}, {12, 13, 14, 15} };
      int [][][] z = { x, y };
      System.out.println("" + sum(x) + " Expected: 59");
      System.out.println("" + sum(y) + " Expected: 107");
      System.out.println("" + sum(z) + " Expected: 166");
   }
   //sums up 2d array
   public static int sum (int [][] a)
   {
      int sum = 0;
      for(int b = 0; b < a.length; b++)
      {
         for(int c = 0; c < a[b].length; c++)
         {
            sum += a[b][c];
         }
      }
      return sum;
   }
   //sums up 3d array
   public static int sum (int [][][] a)
   {
      int sum = 0;
      for(int d = 0; d < a.length; d++)
      {
         for(int e = 0; e < a[d].length; e++)
         {
            for(int f = 0; f < a[d][e].length; f++)
            {
               sum += a[d][e][f];
            }
         }
      }
      return sum;
    }
}
```

So the first part of my assignment was to finish the sum method so that the output is the expected sum. Now I have to change the the sum methods so that they complete their tasks using one loop. I don't even know where to start with this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use nested streams instead

Comment: I don't think you can sum any list or array without a loop *somewhere*. Therefore, nesting it or not, you can't use only one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550662

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20860423/106261

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
```

Use this  `int sumA=IntStream.of(AA).sum();`
AA is our int array.

You have multidimensional arrays so you have to map all in a stream.
So you use this try it.

```
  IntStream intStream = Arrays.stream(a).flatMapToInt(x -> Arrays.stream(x));
  int sum = intStream.sum();
```

Comment: Does that need any imports? and where would I put that in the code?

Comment: @Philip `import` goes above the top `public class`. And you need Java8 for this

Comment: ehhhh yes   :D Are you sure that u initialize array the right way?

Comment: i am giving you the whole code in a minute  :)

Comment: @cricket_007 oh yes I know that import goes above public class, I meant where would I put int sumA=IntStream.of(AA).sum(); ?

Comment: @Philip Well... within the second inner loop of the `int[][][]` method you can replace `sum += a[d][e][f]` and it's loop with `sum += IntStream.of(a[d][e]).sum()`