# How can I write this variable in the right way?

Tags: java, cplex

I have to write in Java (with Cplex) the variable x[i][j] that is the sum on k of x[i][j][k].
i,j and k are the indices of three sets. 
I have already declare x[i][j][k], but i would like to know the right expression.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider clarifying the question to show what you've tried, how far you've gotten, and more precisely where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be confusing yourself regarding the type of x[i][j].  Is it a set with several elements, indexed by k, or is it a number representing their sum?  You seem to start out this step in computation with the first answer and conclude with the second.

A solution to this is to use another variable to store the result, maybe something like:

```
sums[i][j] = sum(x[i][j]);
```

where `sum(list)` is a function that takes in a list, starts with a return value of 0, and iterates over the elements of the input list adding each one to the return value, then returns that value.  You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4550662/798371) for some ideas about how to implement that.

Comment: I'm sorry. What i mean is that for now i have a variable x[i][j][k] that is binary, according to the values of i,j and k.It's 1 if the vehicle k goes from i to j. Now i want to declare another variable that is the sum on k of the first one. Considering i and j like two nodes, in this way i know the total flow of the arc between them, because k is the index of the vehicles

Comment: Then in the `sum` function, you just add one to the return value for each value that is true. `if(list[k]) { returnValue++;}`